# Does every complex $n$ by $n$ matrix have at least one eigenvector? Like is it possible for a complex square matrix to have zero eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that the question has been answered regarding whether every $n$ by $n$ matrix has $n$ number of eigenvectors but what about at least one?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, the characteristic polynomial, $\operatorname {det}(A-x I)$, has a root $\lambda $.  Then $A-\lambda I$ is singular,  so there's an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Eigenvalues are roots of the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), so by the fundamental theorem of algegbra, there exist $n$ [possibly complex] eigenvalues, which must correspond with some eigenvectors, so there does exist at least one eigenvector.